# accessing the data from the jQuery source array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have been given this code by the ui designer and I dont know how to post the
     selected source array data to a php script so I can query it with MySQL, I am sorry I
     a beginner with JQuery, I would like to query the array like in a form option select      style, or would it be better to use an associative array?

```
<div id='content'>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var source = [
            "Select Your location",
            "North London",
            "South London",
            "West London",
            "East London",
            "City of London",  
        ];

        // Create a jqxDropDownList  
        $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({ 
            source: source,    
            selectedIndex: 0, 
            width:   '250px', 
            height: '35px', 
            theme: 'summer' 
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='jqxDropDownList'>
```

Comment: need to use ajax or json !

check here : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968296/how-to-i-send-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa`

Comment: just going to check that out thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to just use this fancy dropdown as normal dropdown, here is the example (no need for ajax):

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var source = [
            "Select Your location",
            "North London",
            "South London",
            "West London",
            "East London",
            "City of London",  
        ];

        // Create a jqxDropDownList  
        $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({ 
            source: source,    
            selectedIndex: 0, 
            width:   '250px', 
            height: '35px', 
            theme: 'summer' 
        });

        $('#jqxDropDownList').bind('select', function (event) { 
            $('#location').val($("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList('getSelectedItem').label);        
        });

    });


</script>
<div id='jqxDropDownList'></div>

<form>
<input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="not selected" />
<input type="submit" value="selected!">
</form>

<div><?php if (isset($_GET['location'])) print('You selected: '.$_GET['location']); ?></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Download and use jqwidgets library.
2. Bind a select event to jqwidgets dropdown, which puts selected value to normal (hidden) form element.
3. Submit and use in PHP as normal submitted value

More information: [JQWidgets dropdown homepage](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdropdownlist/index.htm#demos/jqxdropdownlist/defaultfunctionality.htm)